# Adding multiple buttons in UITextfield iOS swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

I doing one project in swift.In that i want to add multiple buttons in UItextfield.While typing in textfield,a dropdown will come with results.while selecting that result,It should be added like a button in textfield.For example I want it in a "Mail To: format".Please help me to do this.Give some idea

Comment: show some screen which type of output u need

Comment: just a textview with dropdown only..

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for - https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tltagscontrol

Comment: @iamyogish  expecting the same.thank you.I will try this